# I am trying to integrate UFT with Azure devops(VSTS) but getting error by using the UFT plugin in Azure devops(RUNFROMFILESYSTEM Plugin)

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-devops-extensions, uft14

My test cases is in my local system. I have given the path of my test cases in RUNFROMFILESYSTEM Plugin but i am getting error as "##[error]Could not find file 'C:\Shiva_work_tasks\RunFromFileSystemTask_cfbe1493-3bb1-44d5-ac87-7f14a148a6f2\1.0.4\task.json'.

Please help me on this or anyone encountered with this type of issues.

Answer (score 0):

The Azure cloud should communicate your local system. It is possible by installing a VSTS agent with Personal Access Token.
Make sure your local system which is having UFT scripts , that should have powershell Script 4.0 or above.

For More Details please look into the attachment , available in github.
https://github.com/hpsa/ADM-TFS-Extension/files/3116791/UFT_VSTS.docx
you can find my comments there.

Answer (score 0):

I tested with private agent and got the same error as you:

[image]

I searched for the task.json based on the file path provided in the error message and found that task.json does not exist under the 1.0.4 folder.

This should be a problem with the third plugin, I saw you submit a [feedback](https://github.com/hpsa/ADM-TFS-Extension/issues/31) on github of this extension, hope the product team there can give a valuable  reply.

Comment: I resolved this issue but encounter while publishing the report ....Any one faced this error "#[error]System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException: The term 'Invoke-ReportTask' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again."

Comment: @Shiva Mohanty Can you share your solution with this issue? Only after this problem is solved can we continue to investigate the publish test result error

Comment: Please follow the document to resolve the 1st issue but i am stuck with the publish report .....https://github.com/hpsa/ADM-TFS-Extension/files/3116791/UFT_VSTS.docx